# Javascript function not called properly

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I am trying to click on the first radio button and it will assign variables distSelected and weapon some values from the object engDistanceObject. I suspect my HTML might not be written correctly... specifically the input tags.

https://jsfiddle.net/Natronox/sbojaxm4/#&togetherjs=zb80KxkQzm

```
var engDistanceObject = {
short:  ["100m-300m","416 Assault Rifle"],
long:   ["300m-1000m","M110 DMR"]
};

var distSelected;
var weapon;

function distanceClick(item){
distSelected = engDistanceObject.item[0];
weapon = engDistanceObject.item[1];
console.log(distSelected,weapon);
};
```

Comment: Please note the commented out stuff is not necessary to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use your short and long properties instead of item.  You don't have an item property name in your object.

.short[0]

.short[1]

Comment: Yes but in the input tag, I pass 'onclick="distanceClick(short)"'. Doesn't that mean item becomes short... therefore accessing engDistanceObject.short.[0]?

Comment: Reason that I do this is because you will be able to select the long property on the second radio button

Comment: The way you are doing it will cause a conflict.  You pass item into the function but your object has two properties.  Which property is item referring to?

Comment: Unless you are trying to set a value in the object using an item array.

Comment: See answer below.  He's got it :)

Answer (score 0):

To access dynamic properties, you can't use the `.` syntax. It ignores variables that might have the same name as the property you're trying to access, and instead will try to access the non-existent `item` property.

Instead, use the bracket syntax `[]`, which allow a string to be used to access dynamic properties. This means that you need to pass a string as a parameter to your function.

Your HTML event handlers will need quotes around the parameters:

```
onclick="distanceClick('long')"
```

And then use the bracket syntax in your JS:

```
function distanceClick(item){
    distSelected = engDistanceObject[item][0];
    weapon = engDistanceObject[item][1];
    console.log(distSelected, weapon);
}
```